# How to pass in stdin input to a go app from dockerimage

Tags: docker

I am still not well versed with docker so apologies in advance.

I need to run this package: https://github.com/sclevine/yj

What I have done so far is

1. pulled this image in my `GOPATH` (i don't think it was needed to be on `GOPATH` though).
2. Then i did `docker build yj .`

Now, I don't know how to execute the command to convert github `yaml` to `hcl`. I have tried following commands but all gave "help" message from the program

```
docker run -it <image_id> /bin/bash
docker run -it <image_id> /bin/yj
docker run -it <image_id>
docker run -it <image_id> -yc
docker run -it <image_id> /bin/yh -yc
docker run -it <image_id> /bin/yh
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash ad5d67b05c22
docker run -it <image_id> -xyc
docker run -it <image_id> yj -yc
```

Few commands like `docker run -it <image_id> yj -yc`, didn't show any error. the cursoer stayed in console (without any prompt). I tried pasting my `yaml` file but nothing happened.

Comment: Is your container running ? If yes why not try docker exec command and and then place the input

Comment: Command-line tools like this aren't a great match for Docker, and if you're building them from source anyways, there's not a whole lot of advantage.  Just `go install` it and the binary will be in `$GOPATH/bin` and you can run it without needing any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to clarify here:

1. Your build command has syntax error and it should be something like `docker build -t yj .` which will build a new image with name `yj` and tag `latest`
2. Whenever you run `docker run -it <image_id> /bin/bash` it will create a new container and you will have to explicitly remove it. You can see all those containers using `docker ps -a`. For one-off usage, please add a flag `--rm` so that docker will remove the container whenever the container exits.
3. Once the image `yj` has been built, here are some of the commands that you can run to see how it works

```
docker run --rm -i yj <<EOF
key: value
EOF
```

or

```
echo key: value | docker run --rm -i yj
```